# Knockout template not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, knockout.js

I have the following template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="testTemplate">
    <div class="itemName">Hello World</div>
    <div class="itemDescription">This is a template that pops up</div>
</script>
```

I'm calling it in an onClick event like this:

```
        $("<div/>", {
            class: "itemView",
            id: name,
            "data-bind": "template: { name: 'testTemplate' }"
        }).appendTo("body").draggable();
```

When I click the button to view the item, the div pops up but it's empty.  The HTML is just an empty DIV like this:

```
<div class="itemView" id="Item1" data-bind="template: { name: 'testTemplate' } "></div>
```

What am I missing?

**update** I have greatly simplified this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to call ko.applyBindings() again. But the usual approach in Knockout is to put the div in your HTML and use the [visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding to control whether the div is rendered.

Comment: There might be countless items opened... but I'll try applying the bindings again, thanks.

Comment: That's all it took.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally this is not how I would go about this sort of functionality.

I would have the `div` already on the page but hidden.

CSS

```
.itemView{ display: none; }
.show{ display: block; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="itemView" id="Item1" data-bind="with: myObject, css: { 'show': (myObject() !== null) }">
    <div class="itemName">Hello World</div>
    <div class="itemDescription">This is a template that pops up</div>
</div>
```

Then when you raise the click event, populate the `myObject` object with the selected object. Knockout will take care of everything.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise it was multiple items. Let me have a think